# About Java Access Specifier Binding

Tags: java, security, binding, runtime

In an interview, they asked me:
When Java Access Specifier (Public, Default, Protected, Private) is bind to the Java code? Early Binding or Late Binding??
I said: Early Binding.
Then they said:
We need security during Runtime. Then how it is achieved?
I don't know. Please HELP.
And THANKS IN ADVANCE.....

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Your answer to first Question is right. Type check is done at `compile time` (early binding). Because `java` is *statically typed*.

**2)** When the Questioner talks about Run-time security, I think he must be talking about run-time code security, access to resources, alien code access/restrictions, encryption, cryptography, sandbox etc.

**Read this. This is overall overview. This will give you nice, clear and crisp head-start** >> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/overview/jsoverview.html

**And than Go into details, subject by subject** >> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/index.html